# Template email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

How can I create a template email in Gmail that will bring up the template and let me fill in a couple of fields in the Recipient list, Subject and Body of the email?

Comment: [Google thinks it’s possible](http://www.google.com/search?q=template+email+gmail), but I haven’t tested it so I won’t post it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gmail feature *Canned responses* does just that.

1. Click `Compose` and write your template
2. Click on `Canned responses` and then `New canned response...` to save it

[image]

Next time you need to write a template email, click on `Canned responses` and select the template from the Load list.

Comment: Canned responses doesn't save Subjects, so sadly, it does not do 'just that'. (OP specified subject as one of the fields he wished to be saved in the template)

Comment: @John: The OP asked for the ability to modify the subject.

Comment: *`Canned responses doesn't save Subjects`:* that's no longer true. It does save the subject but won't fill the field if it's not empty, i.e., it only works if you didn't write any subject yet.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail have changed a lot since this question was posted. Nowadays instead of *Canned Reponses* it use the term *Templates* but it's disabled by default.

- To enable *Templates* go to Gmail **Settings**, then to the **Advanced** tab.
- To create, change, insert or delete a template, click on Compose, then on the More menu > Templates

For details see [Create email templates](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308990?hl=en).

NOTE: Templates could be used for auto-replies by using a filter.