# Send template email in Gmail (recipients, subject, body)

Tags: gmail

I need to periodically send similar emails with Gmail. The same recipient(s), the same subject line, modify body manually before sending. Example: monthly update.

"Canned responses" are almost doing what I want, but they are not saving the recipient.

Is this feature available in Gmail or is there extension allowing for this? I can probably create "bookmarklet" (JavaScript + mailto), but this looks like too "hacky" solution for what looks like simple core feature.

Comment: [Related](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25022)

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available in Google Chrome extension Deskun. You can save the sender, also add CC, BCC in the template.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a message to send to many people via email that you want
>   personalized for each recipient, use mail merge. You can create a
>   batch of personalized email messages that are formatted identically
>   and use the same text and graphics. Only specific sections of the
>   email message vary and are personalized. Mail merge—unlike
>   broadcasting a message to a group of people—makes each recipient of
>   the message the sole recipient.

*you should read this -* https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-send-bulk-email-messages-0f123521-20ce-4aa8-8b62-ac211dedefa4

*also this might help -*  http://www.boomeranggmail.com/l/how-to-send-recurring-emails.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest SendGrid.

It's a website made to send emails to hundreds of people but it would work for you as for a newsletter

If you have a student email address you can get more than 500 emails per month (I don't remember the numbers)

I have an account on there but I haven't used it yet.